# Injected Service in HttpInterceptor not initialized

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to inject a service into an HttpInterceptor, here is the simple service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class LoginLoadingService {
   constructor() { }
   public loaded: boolean;
   isLoaded() {
       if (this.loaded === undefined) {
             this.loaded = true;
       }
       return this.loaded;
  }    
}
```

And the interceptor

```
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from 
'@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { LoginLoadingService } from './loading.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
@Injectable()
export class LoginLoadingInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public loginLoadingService: LoginLoadingService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loginLoadingService.loaded = false
    return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      this.loginLoadingService.loaded = true;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}
```

And in my app.module

```
providers: [
  LoginLoadingService,
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: LoginLoadingInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }
]
```

The HttpInterceptor is firing fine, but the loginLoadingService is not defined in the intercept() method. I tried to add deps to the interceptor in app.module, but that gave me this error

> params.map is not a function

Not sure what the issue is here

Comment: Good news, your error isn't realted to your interceptor. Bad news, I don't know where your error comes from. Could you post the whole stack trace fo your error ? And in text please, no screenshot

Comment: Sigh disregard, I forgot to inject the service into something downstream :(

Comment: I wonder what would make your interceptor to trigger ? I can't see httpclient call in code you have posted!

Comment: Are you doing http call somewhere else ?

Comment: @IsaacLevin Could you please share as well with us what exactly you had to do to fix your problem? I'm struggling exactly with the same problem and being new to Angular, not able to figure it out (yet).

Answer (score 56):

Define dependencies for interceptors like below:

for example, we have `AuthInterceptor` and we have injected `LocalStorageService` and `SessionStorageService`.

in app.module.ts we add interceptor `AuthInterceptor` :

```
   {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AuthInterceptor,
        multi: true,
        deps: [LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService]
    },
```

This will work.

Comment: Just make sure that you catch the error using the arrow syntax `catchError(error => this.handleServerError(error))` and not just `catchError(this.handleServerError)`, otherwise it won't work

Comment: @zolastro I can't believe this is the solution to my 102301293123 problems. why? whyyy? WWWWHHHYYYYY????

Comment: Thanks @zolastro This was exactly my issue. You could also do `catchError(this.handleServerError.bind(this))`

Answer (score 7):

The answer provided by @Hadi is the correct one.Thought I will add to this. 
 The reason behind using **deps** in app module is explained in details in this article. 
https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html#new-staticinjector-apis

Newer versions of Angular make use of StaticInjector where the DI framework of angular comes into play. We basically ask the Angular to provide us the singleton instance of a service when required by just injecting them as **providers** in app.module.

This is nothing but a shorthand version of **{provide: token_name, useClass:class_name}**

So we are requesting angular to inject a token of type (class) using the above code. Now if we need the token to be injected with existing service dependencies then we ask the token to be injected like this

**{provide: token_name, useClass:class_name, deps: [deps_name]}**

And that is why,the below resolves to the static injection of the interceptor

**{
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AuthInterceptor,
        multi: true,
        deps: [LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService]
    },**